# License requirement for adding a new item in customized SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-addin, access

When an external customer is having access to SharePoint list , do they need license to create a new item in the customized SharePoint list ?

Answer (score 1):

If they are a *Guest* account, no (Azure B2B invites). If they are a standard Member account (User account in Azure AD), then you must assign them a license that includes a SharePoint Online plan.